# Data Grid View Auto Filter and mysql Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows

I followed the tutorial below to create autofilter in my datagridview but i don't know how to get data from Mysql phpmyadmin into the filter

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480727.aspx

Comment: Please try to read [this doc](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/import_export.html) for phpMyAdmin, there is an import/export section

Comment: VB.NET IsNot VB6 AndAlso IsNot vbScript.  Please read [Ask] AndAlso take the [Tour]